# Why do I have to do two train steps for fine-tuning InceptionV3 in Keras?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, keras, pre-trained-model

I don't understand why I have to call the `fit()`/`fit_generator()` function twice in order to fine-tune InceptionV3 (or any other pretrained model) in Keras (version 2.0.0). 
The [documentation](https://keras.io/applications/) suggests the following:

Fine-tune InceptionV3 on a new set of classes

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K

# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
# and a logistic layer -- let's say we have 200 classes
predictions = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)

# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile the model (should be done *after* setting layers to non-trainable)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# train the model on the new data for a few epochs
model.fit_generator(...)

# at this point, the top layers are well trained and we can start fine-tuning
# convolutional layers from inception V3. We will freeze the bottom N layers
# and train the remaining top layers.

# let's visualize layer names and layer indices to see how many layers
# we should freeze:
for i, layer in enumerate(base_model.layers):
   print(i, layer.name)

# we chose to train the top 2 inception blocks, i.e. we will freeze
# the first 172 layers and unfreeze the rest:
for layer in model.layers[:172]:
   layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[172:]:
   layer.trainable = True

# we need to recompile the model for these modifications to take effect
# we use SGD with a low learning rate
from keras.optimizers import SGD
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# we train our model again (this time fine-tuning the top 2 inception blocks
# alongside the top Dense layers
model.fit_generator(...)
```

Why don't we call `fit()`/`fit_generator()` only once?
As always, thanks for your help!

**E D I T :**

The below given answers by Nassim Ben and David de la Iglesia are both very good. I'd like to highly recommend the link given by David de la Iglesia: [Transfer Learning](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InceptionV3 is a very deep and complex network, it has been trained to recognize some things, but you are using it for another classification task. This means that when you use it, it's not perfectly adapted to what you do.

So the aim they want to achieve here, is use some of the features learnt already by the trained network and modify a bit the top of the network (the highest level features, the closest to your task).

So they removed the very top layer and added some more, new and untrained ones. They wanted to train that big model for their task, using the feature extraction made by the 172 first layers and learning the last ones to be adapted to your task.

In that part that they want to train, there is one subpart with already learned parameters and another with new, randomly initialized, parameters. The thing is that the layers that are already learnt, you only want to fine tune them and not relearn them from scratch... The model has no way to distinguish layers that it should just finetune and layers that should be learnt completely. If you only do one fit on the [172:] layers of the model, you will lose the interesting features learnt on the huge dataset of imagnet. You don't want that, so what you do is :

1. Learn "good enough" last layers by setting the whole inceptionV3 to not trainable, this will produce a good result.
2. The layers newly trained will be good and if you "unfreeze" some of the top layers they won't be perturbated too much, they will only be fine tuned, just how you want.

So to summarize, when you want to train a mix of "already learnt" layers with new layers, you bring the new ones up to date and then train on everything to fine tune them.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer :) 
I think the main sentence is: "The model has no way to distinguish layers that it should just finetune and layers that should be learnt completely". 
Is there any rule of thumb for training the last layers "well enough"?

Comment: No rule of thumb, the way they did it is the good one. Freeze the pretrained layers, train only on those lasts, it will bring them to a good enough performance then finetune alltogether to get the best performance. :)

Comment: Yeah! But how many epochs are good enough in order to train only the last layers before fine-tuning? 
Is it another hyper-parameter which I have to find on trial?

Comment: No, just let it train until the validation loss is at minimum... just regular training... use earlystopping if you want

Comment: Oh, quite easy :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you append 2 layers with random initializations on top of an already tuned convnet and you try to finetune some convolutional layers without "warming up" the new layers, the high gradients of this new layers will blow up the (useful) things learned by those convolutional layers.

That's why your first `fit` only trains this 2 new layers, using the pre-trained convnet like some sort of "fixed" feature extractor.

After that, your 2 Dense layers don't have high gradients and you are able to finetune some of the pre-trained convolutional layers. That's what you are doing on your second `fit`.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer.

Comment: For clarification: first I train only the new layers and secondly I can fine-tune the pretrained layers. This means, IN THE LIMIT I could fine-tune the whole model. But this isn't sensible, as I don't want to lose the already learned features. Is there any guideline to choose the "right" amount of layers which I should fine-tune?

Comment: It depends on your new dataset. Check this: .http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/ .  Read the section on *When and how to fine-tune?*